# Запятая перед "в том числе"

Tags: пунктуация

> На 01.01.2012 года в организации трудятся более 200 человек в том числе 3 доктора и 24 кандидатов наук.

1. Перед "в том числе" надо ставить запятую?
2. 24 кандидата или кандидатов наук?

Answer (score 1):

~1. Да. 
Обособляются присоединительные конструкции, которые содержат дополнительные замечания или разъяснения, вводимые в середину или в конец предложения. Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами даже, особенно, в особенности, например, в частности, главным образом, в том числе, притом, и притом, и (в значении «и притом»), да, да и, да и вообще и др.
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm

*Тут иногда возникает сложность в определении необходимости запятой **после** присоединительных слов, но это не наш случай. Запятая перед такой конструкцией вполне однозначна.*

~2. 24 кандидата. 
Ориентируйтесь на последнюю цифру. Числительные заканчивающиеся на 2, 3, 4 требуют после себя формы родительного падежа.

***На 01.01.2012 года в организации трудятся более 200 человек, в том числе 3 доктора и 24 кандидата наук.***

Возможно в данном случае лучше будет "в организации *трудится* более 200 человек...", но это допустимые варианты. 
Об этом здесь:
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm
(§184, п. 10)